# Writing an older version of Berkeley DB in Java

Tags: java, berkeley-db

Is it possible to write out an older version of Berkeley DB using the Java interface? The version being 1.85/1.86.

Comment: What do you mean by "write out" ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Berkeley DB does not have an ability to write older format databases files at all regardless of the API (C, Java, C++, etc.).